# String value decode utf-8

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8, pyqt4, decode

I want to decode string values ​​to utf-8. But it doesn't change.
So, here is my code:

```
self.textEdit_3.append(str(self.new_header).decode("utf-8") + "\n")
```

The result image is here:

[image]

The original output value is:

```
['matchkey', 'a', 'b', 'd', '안녕'] # 안녕 is Korean Language
```

I changed the default encoding for encoding / decoding with unicode to utf-8 instead of ascii. On the first line I added this code:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Why doesn't the string value change?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix your code like this:

```
header = str(self.new_header).decode('string-escape').decode("utf-8")
self.textEdit_3.append(header + "\n")
```

You do not need the `setdefaultencoding` lines.

---

**Expanantion**:

The original value is a list containing byte-strings:

```
>>> value = ['matchkey', 'a', 'b', 'd', '안녕']
>>> value
['matchkey', 'a', 'b', 'd', '\xec\x95\x88\xeb\x85\x95']
```

If you convert this list with `str`, it will use `repr` on all the list elements:

```
>>> strvalue = str(value)
>>> strvalue
"['matchkey', 'a', 'b', 'd', '\\xec\\x95\\x88\\xeb\\x85\\x95']"
```

The `repr` parts can be decoded like this:

```
>>> strvalue = strvalue.decode('string-escape')
>>> strvalue
"['matchkey', 'a', 'b', 'd', '\xec\x95\x88\xeb\x85\x95']"
```

and this can now be decoded to unicode like this:

```
>>> univalue = strvalue.decode('utf-8')
>>> univalue
u"['matchkey', 'a', 'b', 'd', '\uc548\ub155']"
>>> print univalue
['matchkey', 'a', 'b', 'd', '안녕']
```

---

**PS**:

Regarding the problems reading files with a utf-8 bom, please test this script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, codecs, tempfile

text = u'a,b,d,안녕'
data = text.encode('utf-8-sig')

print 'text:', repr(text), len(text)
print 'data:', repr(data), len(data)

f, path = tempfile.mkstemp()
print 'write:', os.write(f, data)
os.close(f)

with codecs.open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    string = f.read()
    print 'read:', repr(string), len(string), string == text
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160658/discussion-on-answer-by-ekhumoro-string-value-decode-utf-8).